# predicate next_board/3

Tags: prolog

I would like to write a predicate for tic-tac-toe game, that generate possible   successor board configuration for given player and board. After typing this input:

```
 next_board([[x,o,x],[x,x,o],[o,e,e]],x,N).
```

the output should be displayed as following:

```
 N=[[x,o,x],[x,x,o],[o,e,e]];
 N=[[x,o,x],[x,e,o],[o,x,e]];
 N=[[x,o,x],[x,e,o],[o,e,x]];
```

Comment: Please show your effort at solving this.

Comment: Do your own homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate possible successor boards you basically have to "replace" single empty cells (marked with `e`) with your player chip.

At first sight you might be tempted to use [select/4](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/4) but it would replace every empty cell in a row with your player chip. So, you might be better off using `append/3` predicate with something like this:

```
next_board(Board, Player, NextBoard):-
  append(Head, [Row|Tail], Board),  % Take a single row from the board
  append(RowHead, [e|RowTail], Row), % Take a single empty cell
  append(RowHead, [Player|RowTail], NRow), % and replace it with your player chip
  append(Head, [NRow|Tail], NextBoard). % Now build a next possible board
```

You might as well make recursive procedures to achieve the same logic without using `append/3`.